# JSF unnable to get parameter from URL

Tags: jsf-2

I try to get a parameter from the URL but I can't. I do this in my jsf

```
   <f:metadata>  
   <f:viewParam name="key" value="#{confirmationMB.key}"  required="true"   />  
   <f:viewAction action="#{confirmationMB.confirmer()}"/>  
   </f:metadata>
```

and this in my managed bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class confirmationMB {
private String key;  public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
public void confirmer(){

    System.out.println("the key is   "+key);

}
```

my URL is like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/exempler/validate_inscription.xhtml?key=124he
```

I get always **null** as value in System.out..can someone help me please ?

**Edit:**
when I try `<h:outputText value="#{param['key']}" />` in xhtml I can get the key but I don't know how I can insert it into my Bean !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It s ok I find a solution to my problem : I ve add this lines into my managedBean and I can get now the key from the URL

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();   
    String val = (String)req.getParameter("key");
```

I put this solution to help people who may have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="key" value="#{confirmationMB.key}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView"
        listener="#{confirmationMB.confirmer()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Comment: thank you @sQer for your reply ... I just tried this but still have always NULL value `the key is    NULL`

Comment: In fact .. I construct the link like this `String lien = "http://localhost:8080/exemple/validate_inscription.xhtml?key="+key+";``String body =" pour confirmer  "+"<html><body><a href="+lien+">Clique here</a></body></html>";` and then I sent it with javamail

Comment: Could you try <h:outputText value="#{param['key']}" /> in xhtml ? What result ?

Comment: I can get the right result in the jsf ( the exact key in the URL ) .. so how can I get it and save it in the managed bean?

Comment: please @sQer can you help me if you know what should I do to resolve this problem ?